# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'gmtime'

Tags: python, time

This code for some reason does not work although i give similar inputs in both time while calling the function. I just need to get the difference between the time by inputting two tuple/list into difference_in_date_tup().
Code :-

```
import time

def getcurrentdate():
    a = time.gmtime(time.time())
    year = a[0]
    month = a[1]
    day = a[2]
    return day,month,year

def difference_in_date_tup(date1, date2):
    """Input dates as tuple/list: (dd,mm,yyy)"""
    a = int(date1[0]) - int(date2[0])
    b = int(date1[1]) - int(date2[1])
    c = int(date1[2]) - int(date2[2])
    return abs(a), abs(b), abs(c)

#This works.
print difference_in_date_tup([25,16,2015],getcurrentdate())

#But not this.
time = raw_input("Enter date in format dd/mm/yyyy: ")
t = time.split("/")
print t
print difference_in_date_tup(t,getcurrentdate())
```

I get error:-

```
(0, 10, 0)
Enter date in format dd/mm/yyyy: 25/16/2015
['25', '16', '2015']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ninja\Desktop\test.py", line 24, in <module>
    print difference_in_date_tup(t,getcurrentdate())
  File "C:\Users\Ninja\Desktop\test.py", line 4, in getcurrentdate
    a = time.gmtime(time.time())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'gmtime'
```

Comment: Don't name a variable `time` - you are shadowing the standard library `time` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in line -

```
time = raw_input("Enter date in format dd/mm/yyyy: ")
```

At the first line , you are importing module `time` this sets the `time` name to point to that `module` , but after executing the above line, the `time` name now points to the string that the user inputted, hence if you try to access `time` after that you will get the string and not the `time` module.

I would recommend you rename this variable to something else.